# How to add windows client machines IP’s and names in squid proxy so the logs output as clients name instead IP

Tags: centos, proxy, squid, squidguard

I have configured squid proxy server on centos stream and its up and running perfectly
I want access.log output as windows client usernames instead of machine IP . As example below .

current output

```
1656571863.985      0 172.30.0.104 TCP_DENIED/403 3864 CONNECT mtalk.google.com:5228 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

in above example client machine IP address i want username instead.

Comment: Squid has no way to see user names who are logged into the windows machine. Web browsers simply don't send this information to the proxy. You need to require authentication in the Squid to force clients to provide user names, so users will enter proxy usernames and passwords and Squid will log usernames. If you want to make this more transparent, you may succeed to enable NTLM or, better, Kerberos authentication on the proxy, create users with same passwords, and join the Squid into Active Directory, so the authentication could use the domain credentials for the Single Sign On.

Comment: Yes thanks for details clarification.